# Ошибка при вызове снипета 2 раз в шаблоне MODX EVO

Tags: modx

Написал снипет для выбора из базы уникальных id ресурсов для вызова в DosLister  для списка только необходимых параметров фильтра товаров на странице каталога (например, производители или цвета). Уникальность применяется для того, так как товары с разными размерам и цветом имеют свой ресурс. Для вызова в каталоге товаров использую hidemenu=0 чтоб не плодить одинаковые товары в каталоге.

В общем вот код снипета и вызов списка параметров:

```html
<?php

$id = isset($id) ? $id : ''; 
// функция извлечение уникалных значений из массива 
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 
    
    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
}  
// получаем первый массив 
$sql="SELECT id, pagetitle FROM ".$modx->getFullTableName('site_content')." WHERE parent=".$id." AND published=1 AND hidemenu=0 ORDER BY pagetitle ASC";
$q=$modx->db->query($sql);
$content = $modx->db->makeArray($q);

// получаем второй массив
$sql2="SELECT contentid, value  
       FROM ".$modx->getFullTableName('site_tmplvar_contentvalues')." 
    WHERE tmplvarid=80";
$q2=$modx->db->query($sql2);
$tv = $modx->db->makeArray($q2);
 
// объединяем первый и второй массив
foreach($content as $key => $value){
    foreach($tv as $value2){
        if($value['id'] === $value2['contentid']){
            $content[$key]['value'] = $value2['value'];
        }               
    }
}

// получаем уникальный массив
$details = unique_multidim_array($content,'value'); 


// вывод результатов из массива
foreach($details as $row)
{
  echo $row['id'].','; 
}

?>
```

Сам вызов значений параметра фильтра:

```html
[[DocLister? 
    &documents=`[[uniqueIdcolor? &id=`[*id*]`]]` 
    &idType=`documents`
    &tvList=`cvet`
    &tvPrefix=`` 
    &id=`filterColors`
    &tpl=`filterColorsTpl` 
]]

// шаблон вызова

<a data-target="[+cvet+]" data-type="color" class="selectable detailed"><span class="color-cart color"><img src="[[ColorSelect? &docid=`[+id+]`]]" class="img-color" alt=""><span class="size">[+cvet+]</span></span></a>
```

Все работает, но при вызове снипета второй раз в шаблоне, ошибка 500 в браузере. В общем не ясно, такая же ошибка у меня появляется при синтетической ошибке кода в снипете.

Почему снипет нельзя вызвать второй раз... или даже если делаешь копию, а заменяешь только tv параметр для сбора?

Answer (score 1):

При повторном вызове сниппета, у вас происходит повторное определение функции, это вызывает ошибку. Попробуйте так:

```
if (!function_exists('unique_multidim_array')) {
    function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено удалением функции извлечение уникальных значений из массива и заменой нижнего кода:

```html
// получаем уникальный массив
$content = array_unique(array_column($content, 'value'));

// вывод результатов из массива
foreach($content as $key =>$row)
{
echo '<li><a data-target="'.$row.'" data-type="brand" class="selectable detailed"><i class="box"></i> '.$row.'</a></li>'; 
}
return $output;
```

Вызов напрямую, без DocLister